# How to include specific button on click action within url

Tags: html, css, url, shopify, liquid

I am working on a shopify store and need to create url links to directly go to "write a review" form which opens up onclick on a button in each product page.

This link has been created to directly search for text "reviews" and go the that position.. instead , I am looking to include opening the form (Click on "Write a review" button) directly in the url instead of expecting customer to search and click on it

[https://thebrownbling.com/products/ajwa-madina-saudi-dates#:~:text=reviews](https://thebrownbling.com/products/ajwa-madina-saudi-dates#:%7E:text=reviews)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IncO0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function inside the >
admin > online store > themes > live theme > Actions > edit code.

Search your product.liquid or similar (depending your theme, the name is different) and add a script at the end of the code.
in this script, create a remove css for the id: #form_6728808399028

```
like this:
$("#form_6728808399028").css("display", "block");
```

(if you try to insert this script in the console, the form to write a review is visible after running the code)

try using the url as a variable, if the href = your url with review link, show the review for: try copy and paste the next code in your console:

```
<script>
var url = "https://thebrownbling.com/products/ajwa-madina-saudi-dates#:%7E:text=reviews";
$(function(){
  if (location.href==url){
    $("#form_6728808399028").css("display", "block");
  }
});
</script>
```